# search bar input not working for other supported languages

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using the same `HTML`/`CSS` properties for a website that supports two languages. The search bar works fine in English but I cannot input anything when I change to the other language.

The website: http://barajon.com/store/

You can change the language by clicking the green flag on the top menu.

The `HTML` of the search bar:

```
<!-- Header Search Begin -->
<form class="h-search" method="post" action="search.php" name="productsearchform" onsubmit="javascript:return TXS_funcSubmitForm();" style="border-style: none; width: auto;">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="simple_search" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_data[by_title]" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_data[by_descr]" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_data[by_sku]" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_data[search_in_subcategories]" value="Y" />
    <input type="hidden" name="posted_data[including]" value="all" />              

    <div class="srch-area">
        <input type="text" class="srch-fld" name="{if $TXS_search_id && $active_modules.Predictive_Search ne ""}{$TXS_search_id}{else}posted_data[substring]{/if}" id="TXS_PS_search" id="TXS_PS_search" value="{$search_prefilled.substring|escape}" />
        <input class="sbmit-btn" name="" value="Go" type="submit" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="txs_area" value="C" /> 
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- Header Search End -->
```

Comment: Post the code that creates the text box and the code that differs between the two versions of the site.

Comment: CSS only differs between the two. do you need CSS code or this is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot input text into the text box is that it is being covered by another `DIV`. The part of the `DIV` which is covering the text box is 'invisible' to the user (doesn't have a background colour or a border to signify it's there).

To force your text box to appear in front of the `DIV`, change the text box's `z-index` to a larger number, let's say `9999`. Since `z-index` only applies to positioned elements, you must change the `position` of your text box to either `relative`, `fixed`, or `absolute`.

In your particular example, I would recommend you set the `position` and `z-index` of the `div` that contains the text box instead of the text box itself. In your case I would change the line:

```
<div class="main-menu">
```

to

```
<div class="main-menu" style="position:relative;z-index:9999;">
```

Modifying the class `main-menu` would be the better idea to achieve consistency across your entire site, either way this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I remove `position: relative` from `.banner`, it works:

```
.banner{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}
```

The reason for that is that using relative positioning for `.banner` makes it go **over** `.main-menu`. Thus, clicking on the search field doesn't do anything because technically, you're not clicking *on the search field* at all.

Other method to fix this would be the usage of `z-index` but I think that when you don't really change the relative position of `.banner`, there is no need to use `position: relative`.

Comment: thanks! both approaches work